# Massive Insert from a JSON file using Pg-Promise

Tags: pg-promise

## Load huge JSON file using Pg-Promise helpers and fs stream.

I'm using pg-promise and I want to make massive inserts into a table using pgp.helpers. I've seen solution like Multi-row insert with pg-promise and also followed Data import for streams (Spex) but still it fails with the same error as in this post https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/issues/8

I tried using a example from the other post on CSV stream(rs.csv()) but when i replaced the same with JSonStream parser I still get the same error.

Can you please share a working example?

`db.tx(t => {
      return streamRead.call(t, stream.pipe(parser), receiver)
  })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to do it, but the below code sure works! 
I have the chunks(row.length) at 20,000 per insert statement you can adjust accordingly based on your needs.

```
stream.pipe(parser)
  parser.on('data', data =>{
    row.push(data)
    if (row.length === 20000) { 
      parser.pause()
      //console.log(row.length)
      db.tx('inserting-products', t => {
        const insert = pgp.helpers.insert(row, cs)
        t.none(insert).then(() => {
          row =[]
          parser.resume()
        })
      })
    }
  })

  parser.on('end', () =>{
    //console.log(row.length)
    if(row.length != 0){
      db.tx('inserting-products', t => {
        const insert = pgp.helpers.insert(row, cs)
        t.none(insert).then(() => {
          console.log('success')
          db.$pool.end()
        })
      })
    }
    if(row.length === 0) {
      console.log('success')
      db.$pool.end()
    }
  })
```

Please let me know in comments if this helps or any other ways to improve the process.

Comment: A single multi-row insert is an atomic operation, it doesn't need a transaction, i.e. if one set of values fails to insert, none will. If you want a transaction for the whole thing, then you need it at a higher level.

Comment: Thanks vitaly-t, Is there anyway to write this same code using spex sequence?

Comment: There is, yes, as shown in [Data Imports](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Data-Imports) ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t I tried but not able to pipe the stream into sequence.. can you post a working sample here?